# Expression with contains , giving error like "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: c#, linq

When I Using C# linq expression with contains , I got an Error like "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".
My Code Segement is,

```
var query = GetUserDataForList();// It contains the data I want
 search = (search == null) ? "" : search;
 string searchText = (search == null) ? "" : search.ToLower().ToString();

 var users = query.Where(a => a.Email.ToLower().Contains(searchText) && a.Email != null).AsEnumerable();
 users = users.Skip(rowsPerPage * (page - 1)).Take(rowsPerPage).AsEnumerable();
```

any idea how to solve that?

Comment: [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: So, `a.Email` can be `null`, huh?

Comment: Make a.Email != null check before the first argument

Comment: In your where clause you are performing your null check after accessing the property, change it to `Where(a => a.Email != null && a.Email.ToLower().Contains(searchText))`

Answer (score 4):

Your conditions in `Where` clause should be like:

```
a.Email != null && a.Email.ToLower().Contains(searchText)
```

Because only then it will short-circuit in case of `null`. Right now even if your `Email` is `null` it will try to use use `ToLower` and give you NRE.

See: [&& Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx)

> The conditional-AND operator (&&) performs a logical-AND of its bool
>   operands, **but only evaluates its second operand if necessary**